# Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION' for project ':demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am trying to use this library : https://github.com/telly/MrVector in my android studio project.
So what I did is to import it as a module in my project and when i tried to sync project 
this error appeared

> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION' for project ':demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Here is where the problem occurs in the Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':library')
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION}@aar"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION' for project ':demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

It's because your project didn't have the `ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION` property in your `gradle.properties` which is not getting imported to your project. you need to add the property.

Here is the [MrVector `gradle.properties`](https://github.com/telly/MrVector/blob/master/gradle.properties) that you probably need to add to your project:

```
VERSION_NAME=0.2.0
VERSION_CODE=2
GROUP=com.telly

POM_NAME=Mr. Vector Library
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=mrvector
POM_PACKAGING=aar

POM_DESCRIPTION=Mr. Vector (VectorDrawableCompat): A 7+ backport of VectorDrawable
POM_URL=https://github.com/telly/MrVector
POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/telly/MrVector
POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:telly/MrVector.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:telly/MrVector.git
POM_LICENCE_NAME=The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
POM_LICENCE_URL=http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo
POM_DEVELOPER_ID=eveliotc
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Evelio Tarazona Caceres

ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=7
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=21
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=21
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=21.1.2

ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=21.0.3
```

Comment: thank you but after i did that this new error appeared 
`Supplied proguard configuration file name is unsupported. Valid values are: [proguard-android-optimize.txt, proguard-defaults.txt, proguard-android.txt]`

Comment: that another unrelated error with your previous problem. Check your modules build.gradle` if they are using a correct build.gradle line like this:       `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`

Comment: The problem is from the library you've imported. Change the following line      `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.pro'), 'proguard-rules.txt'` in the imported library to the lin on my previous comment.

Comment: thank you very much... yes i did it but i am really sorry another error appeared 
`Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while processing D:\android projects\Amas\demo\src\main\res\drawable\logo.xml : For input string: "@integer/logo_viewport_side"
`

Comment: i 'm sorry this my first time to import library

Comment: Okay, no problem. 
Looks like you're incorrectly importing the library. You should only import the `library` module. You don't need the `demo` module. If you want to try the library with the demo, you should run the project library as it is. Import it as a project not as a module or library.